# Mongoose not getting install after command and hangs out

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose, node-modules, npm-install

I am in a problem that when I try to install the mongoose node module than it  starts to download but hangs out every time  the operation can be stopped by ctrl C but the module cant be installed even after several trials
and every time it hangs out but if i try to install any other node module then there is no problem I am having the node version
19 and 18 LTS both i have tried and npm version 9 and 8

```js
npm i mongoose
npm install mongoose
```